# socket.io | npm WARN deprecated isarray@2.0.1: Just use Array.isArray directly

Tags: npm

When I try to install socket.io on local machine I am getting the error below. Does any one know how to resolve below issue?

```
sanket@PC:~/NODE$ sudo npm install socket.io
npm WARN deprecated isarray@2.0.1: Just use Array.isArray directly
learning-express-cluster@1.0.0 /home/sanket


-- date-format@1.1.0  extraneous
-- isarray@2.0.1  extraneous
-- mysql@2.12.0  extraneous
-- sleep@5.0.0  extraneous
-- twilio-api@0.3.3  extraneous


npm WARN learning-express-cluster@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN learning-express-cluster@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN learning-express-cluster@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /home/sanket/node_modules/socket.io
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/sanket/node_modules/socket.io' -> '/home/sanket/node_modules/.socket.io.DELETE'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/sanketues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sanket/NODE/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: hi got answer issue was npm has older version. when we try to install new package it's new one ... just run below command in sequence ..
npm install npm@latest -g

npm update

npm install